# Headphones output is redirected to HDMI sound bar

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones

Since this morning I have a very strange problem.
I have Ubuntu 20.04 with mate installation, and an external monitor with a sound bar.

Although I connect my headphones to my laptop, I still hear sound from laptop speakers.
When I try to force using speakers (in sound preferences), it automatically jumps to HDMI sound:

[image]

If I choose built-in audio again, I see that **Headphones** is selected. However, I still hear sound from the sound-bar.
If I click **Test Speakers** under the **Hardware** tab, I hear sound from headphones.

Any idea how to approach this problem?

================ EDIT =================
I tried to unplug the sound-bar, still the same problem - plugging headphones does not redirect sound to them, when I manually select them I don't hear any sound.